# label-line Not deleted recharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, pie-chart, recharts

hi i am try to give just to part of the pie label and when i no give label the label-line no deletei give example:

<Pie  data={dataPie}  label={renderLabel}  cx="55%"  cy="52%" outerRadius="70%" innerRadius={75} >         <Label fill="black" value={label} position="center" /><LabelList dy={-1}  fill="white" dataKey={renderCount} position="inside" angle="0" stroke="none" /></Pie>

const renderLabel = (data) => {if(data.value > ((parseInt(label)*5)/100)){return data.name;}}

const renderCount = (data) => {if(data.value > ((parseInt(label)*5)/100)){return data.value;}}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpkyl.png)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `labelLine`, just add: `labelLine={false}`

---

```
<Pie labelLine={false} data={dataPie} label={renderLabel} cx="55%" cy="52%" outerRadius="70%" innerRadius={75} > <Label fill="black" value={label} position="center" /><LabelList dy={-1} fill="white" dataKey={renderCount} position="inside" angle="0" stroke="none" /></Pie>
```

Comment: i want to delete the labelLine just from part of piechart you can see in my picture

Comment: Understood but can you please provide all your code please?